# I'm being called names on S.O

Tags: discussion

How do I handle this situation where other users have called me names? Either indirectly, or directly I've been called a name by one of the users in the community. I've flagged the comment, but nothing has happened.

I'm beginning to get scared and nervous. I usually love contributing to S.O but when I get called names it discourages me from contributing because of the unsafe environment I perceive as a result of being called names.

Comment: I will link to the post if requested

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452981/code-works-partially?noredirect=1#comment47084363_29452981

Comment: The tone certainly escalated in the last two comments. Did you have any intervening comments that were since deleted?

Comment: It looks like it was removed by a moderator. Flagging the comment as "not constructive" or possibly even "rude or offensive" is all it takes.

Comment: Someone just deleted the comment.

Comment: ..also, when a user like this only has 1 reputation point, it's usually safe to assume they are a troll.

Comment: I only see your comment "bunch of syntax errors in that code" and the OPs answer "@self2 I'm looking for a more constructive and respectfully response.". That's just the OP being a bad OP, which is his own lookout. But I don't see anything offensive. Was it removed? (BTW: OP self-vandalized. Rolled back.)

Comment: It was removed right after you removed your initial comment on this question

Comment: What's the story with edits #6 and #7 in the question you linked to?

Answer (score 14):

Well, kinda depends on what name they're calling you. I mean, if they're calling you "self" then that's to be expected - it's the name you gave. If they're calling you "rolf" then you might suggest to them that they need glasses.

OTOH, if they're calling you "He Who Does Not Know Enough To Come In From The Rain" then that's pretty clearly meant as an insult - so flag it as "rude" and leave them to wallow in their misery.

The comment you're *probably* referring to read,

> @self You may be an average coder, judging by your comment you fell into the mediocre stereotype, grab your comment and get out of my sight AH.

I don't know if that's name-calling; I have no idea what he meant by "AH"; perhaps he was sighing or had a sudden moment of insight or fell asleep on his keyboard mid-comment? Regardless, the rest of the comment is pretty rude and contributes nothing of value to the conversation - so flagging it is again the proper way to handle this.

Comment: They're not calling me by my username. The user called me an offensive swear word and 2 other things before someone deleted it. AH is an acronym for a swear word. The `h` stands for the word "hole".

Comment: Also I can tell by the tone of your text you're being sarcastic in the way you're going about this.

Comment: And I can tell by the tone of your text that you're being unnecessarily cagey about what you're looking for help with, in spite of *numerous* requests to clarify. My answer is completely accurate - if it doesn't help you, you're gonna have to be more specific in what you're asking. I had to dig through a whole lot of comments to even find the one you were talking about - I wrote this answer after giving up, only to see you'd finally linked to the post (still not quoting the comment itself) here in the meanwhile. I'm not fond of folks wasting time when they could easily avoid it.

Comment: @self: He might be using a slightly flippant and light tone there, but it's nevertheless the only way to go about it. The important parts are: Flag it for cleanup (and if a recurring pattern for that user, mention that), and then disengage. Life is too short to cater to anonymous trolls, and the OP might be a normally decent guy just having a bad day.

Comment: @Deduplicator that is true. And I'm going to take the advice. In the end, I'm just disappointed to see this kind of behavior coming from a moderator in a place like S.O. I expected a more professional response. I understand I'm not owed anything by anyone.

Comment: I'm *really* not trying to give you a hard time, @self - but please, in the future, just be specific. This could've been answered with a single sentence by just about anyone reading it if we'd been aware of the specific situation from the outset; without that though, we're left to guess and try to cover all the bases.

Comment: I don't see anything unprofessional about his response. He just seems more adept to dealing with trolls.

Comment: I don't see anything unprofessional here either..... except from the OP, of course. :)